# Why does the second for loop overwrite the first in Python?

Tags: python

I wanted to add the first seven lines of the file *abc* using a seperate for loop with `j` and the rest of the subsequent lines as the for loop with `i`. However the following script just gives me the 64 lines (only the `i` for loop is executed).

```
f = open("abc","r")
ff = open("xyz","w")

headers = f.readlines()[0:7]

for j in headers:
   print >>ff, j.rstrip('\n')

lines = f.readlines()[-64:]
for i in lines:
  print >>ff, "ss  ", i.rstrip('\n')

f.close()
ff.close()
```

What could be the problem? Also, instead of 64 can I use a user-defined variable using `raw_input()`?

Comment: "instead of 64 can I use a variable from user using raw_input()?": Yes, you can. `int(raw_input())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the first call to `f.readlines()` exhausts the file by reading it all in. You then throw away everything by the first seven lines. Try something like:

```
content = file.readlines()
headers = content[:7] # the starting zero is implied
    :
    :
lines = content[-64:]
```

That way you aren't using `readlines()` on an exhausted file.

Comment: Thinking again, I have NO idea why you should be seeing the 64 lines but not he seven.

Comment: thank you. your hint helped me :). I now read the files two times. first read 7 lines and again rest of the file.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. But note that my solution avoids reading the file a second time. Since the first `.readlines()` call is going to create a list of all the lines in the file, why not take advantage of that to avoid repeated work?

Comment: If you are worried about memory sapce (which at this stage you should not be) you can always `del` the `content` list once both `headers` and `lines` are assigned.